# Spring MVC No handler found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm newbie to spring mvc and trying to develop a very basic login webapp. I get the below error while running the project. I have tried almost everything and could not fix this error since last two weeks. Please can someone help me.

```
May 21, 2013 2:37:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringWeb/WEB-INF/jsp/loginnn.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

My jsp pages resides under WEB-INF/jsp. The method loginpage in my controller is gettting invoked but the view name is not being rendered and resolved. Greatly appreciate your help.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>testspring</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>frontcontrol</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>frontcontrol</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**frontcontrol-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package ="com.shell.spring.testspringapp">
</context:component-scan>
<bean id ="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />      
</bean>

</beans>
```

**Controller class**

```
@Controller

public class Firstcontrol {

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public ModelAndView invokeme(Model m)
{

ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
mav.setViewName("result");
System.out.println("In method");
return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/submit" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String submit(Model m)
{
System.out.println("In submitmethod");
return "submit";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're mapping your DispatcherServlet to '/' try adding `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` to your `spring-servlet.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I saw same error, turned out that you need enable MVC annotations separately

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

In addition to

```
<context:Annotation-config/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<context:component-scan base-package="your base packege " />`

You should check the following section in spring configuration xml. Maybe you copied it from somewhere and forgot to make it your package name. Spring will not be able to scan packages if it so and eventually show this error.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.xml file the configuration file (spring-servler.xml) should be specified to be used by the dispatcher servlet, since your not using the conventional name, which is the [servlet-name]-context.xml.

Since Spring cannot find the configuration file for the dispatcher servlet the viewresolver is never registered.  I assume that 'spring-servler.xml is located within the `WEB-INF` folder in my example, so you may need to adjust.

Also notice I switched the servlet mapping to `/` which helps if you need to resolve static resources, since `/` acts as a catch all as opposed to mapping everything through the dispatcher.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servler.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You could also try using a regular view resolver, if your not using JSTL.

Replace the jstl view resolver:

```
<bean id ="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />      
 </bean>
```

With:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Try returning a `String` from your controller that specifies the view name:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public String loginpage(Model model)
{  
   Employee emp=new Employee();
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("emp", emp);
    return "loginnn";
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'm sorry it was a typo error on spring-servlet.xml. I just edited my post. As you suggested, I have modified both the web.xml and spring-servlet.xml but still get the same error. I tried printing some sysouts inside the loginpage method. It is being invoked and the problem occurs with resolving view name.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I get the below error  May 21, 2013 4:17:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringWeb/login.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: When i replace the URL pattern to  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> i get the error                                                                  May 21, 2013 2:37:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringWeb/WEB-INF/jsp/loginnn.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: Hi Kevin, not much progress. I have created another basic spring mvc app. Though there is no error reported it still shows me HTTP 404 error page.

Comment: I just posted the modified new code, It renders me the result.jsp page but click on submit takes me to HTTP 404 error

Answer (score 0):

@sanjay and @Will Keeling are both right. It is required to use `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` (as the last handler) and enable both `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and `<context:Annotation-config/>`